# Excel Formula - Multiply based on characters in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a formula which isn't quite correct, I would like the formula to look at the first 1 or 2 characters of another cell and based on the contents of this, multiply by a set amount.

It works partially but needs either complete rehash or slight tweak:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A213,1)="Z",(D213*0.85),($D213*(1-K$7))),IF(LEFT(A213,2)="FF",(D213*0.8),""))
```

Currently, if `FF` is found, it reverts to the else if of first statement: `*(1-K$7)` - Tried putting this statement at the end so is last resort but I couldn't work out syntax.

I figure another option would be to have a table on a subsequent sheet with :

```
Z  .85

FF .8
```

etc.

Then reference to this in the formula.

The above solution would make it scalable, although I'm not entirely sure how I would go about it.

Any thoughts?

Example:

Cell K$7 = 30%

```
A       D    E
FF12345 £100 £80  <-- column E = column D * 0.8
Z345674 £200 £170 <-- column E = column D * 0.85
V345565 £300 £210 <-- column E = column D * (1-30%)
```

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show: input, desired output, and explain how the current output differs from the desired.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear-

Typical value for column A:


FF12345
Z345674
V345565


Typical values for column D:

£100
£200
£300


What I would like to do in Column E is look at the cell value of column A and based on the preceding letters (left 1 or 2 characters) multiply column D by a specific amount:

So if ffirst 1 or two characters in column A are: 
FF then * Column D .8
Z then * Column D by .85

I hope this is clearer.

Thanks

P.S Cell K$7 = 30%

Comment: Please put clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link. Did it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Z" has precedence, this should do the trick:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A213,1)="Z",D213*0.85,IF(LEFT(A213,2)="FF",D213*0.8,$D213*(1-K$7))),"")
```

It looks for "Z", then "FF", then goes to `$D213*(1-K$7)`.

The below incorporates your suggested `VLookup`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A213,1)="Z",D213*VLOOKUP("Z",Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0),IF(LEFT(A213,2)="FF",D213*VLOOKUP("FF",Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0),$D213*(1-K$7))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, in the end i made a simpler formula and referenced a second table with vlookup:

=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AV219,Sheet2!$A$3:$B$12,2,FALSE),"")*D219,"")

AV column is a simple =left(A219,1)

Then on Sheet2 I have 

Z .8
F .85
G .8

Many thanks